# App installed in directory on the PATH, but not found. Weird /snap/bin - error message

Tags: command-line, bash, 18.04, snap, paths

I have the app *minikube* in */usr/local/bin/minikube*. When I do *minikube version* with the whole path, I get:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/minikube version
minikube version: v0.28.2
```

When I do *minikube version* without the path, I get:

```
$ minikube version
bash: /snap/bin/minikube: No such file or directory
```

The */usr/local/bin* is included in *PATH*:

```
$ echo $PATH
//usr/local/bin:/home/eric/.local/bin:/home/eric/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

Why isn't *minikube* found without the full path, and what does */snap/bin* have to do with anything? Any help much appreciated!

**Added info as per comment below from @mpr:**
Some time ago, I installed *minikube* with *snap* like this:

```
sudo snap install minikube
```

It was later removed with

```
sudo snap remove minikube
```

Much later, having forgotten about the *snap* install, I installed it from the minikube site with *curl*:

```
curl -Lo minikube https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/v0.28.2/minikube-linux-amd64 && chmod +x minikube && sudo mv minikube /usr/local/bin/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just figured it out: There was a *minikube* directory under *~/snap*, probably left over from a previous install. Fixed the problem doing:

```
$ rm -rf ~/snap/minikube
```

This snap-business is a bit annoying...

Comment: For future readers it may be interesting to know more about what exactly you installed.  It looks like you had a Snap version of minikube, but perhaps also one compiled from scratch and installed to /usr/local?  Snaps are a new application/package management type tool for Ubuntu.  Files related to snaps go in /snap at the system level and ~/snap for each user.

Comment: That's interesting, it looks like the snap removal tool really didn't completely remove things.

Comment: Yup. Must be a problem with my system or a bug. Can't find any bug reports on this, though. Can't reproduce it either, nor find anything in the logs...

Comment: This solved similar problem with removing `rustup` (aka cargo)

Answer (score 1):

Starting some experimentation with Kubernetes on a newly installed Ubuntu 18.04 system I also initially used `snap` to install `minikube`, encountered errors, and then decided to remove the snap.

```
sudo snap install minikube
sudo snap remove minikube
```

I installed `minikube` a second time with `curl`.

```
curl -Lo minikube https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/v0.28.2/minikube-linux-amd64 && chmod +x minikube && sudo mv minikube /usr/local/bin/
```

I also encountered this error :

```
/snap/bin/minikube: No such file or directory
```

This was all performed in a single terminal window.

I did not discover any residual snap files in any of the locations mentioned in the comments above.  The error went away when I killed and started a new terminal window.

The error is NOT reproducable now that I have successfully installed and run `minikube` on this system.